# Вставка ссылки в pdf

Tags: pdf, php, html, javascript

Добрый день.

На моем сайте очень много книг в формате pdf. И вот суть вопроса: как можно вставить текст в pdf документ онлайн. Вариант вставлять текст на компе не подходит, так как на мой сайт книги заливают все зарегистрированные пользователи. Я же не заставлю их проделывать такую операцию. По сему надо онлайн. Есть варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь есть что-то об этом: [PDF Editing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/pdf-editing-in-php).

Answer (score 2):

Zend Framework поддерживает редактирование (создание, изменение и сохранение) pdf-документов. Демо-пример работы: [Zend_Pdf module usage example](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.usage.html).